# OpenGL drawing to an existing HDC using Texture2D

Tags: c, opengl

I am trying to Use OpenGL to render to an existing rendering area of a window that has been created with the Windows API. I get the HDC and create an opengl context using wglCreateContext and wglMakeCurrent. Then I Create a texture and I bind it. although I can clear the buffer to whatever color I choose, I can not render to it. The following code sample should make clear what my problem is.

```
void draw(HDC dhdc){


static unsigned char render_on_device_image_once, odd;
static GLuint texture_id;
size_t sz;

odd = (odd + 1) % 2;
if(!render_on_device_image_once){
        // DO ONCE
    render_on_device_image_once = 1;


    GLubyte pixels[] =
    {
        0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0,
    };
    glGenTextures(1, &texture_id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);


}

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
if(odd)
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0);
else
    glClearColor(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glTranslatef(0, 0, -5);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
glVertex3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
glVertex3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glEnd();

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

SwapBuffers(dhdc);}
```

The above code, which I took (and slightly modified) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22027360/textures-not-working-with-opengl) makes the window area to change between red and blue, but does not render the quads. Has anyone had a similar problem or can spot my mistake?

Thanks.

EDIT:

To add more information, I am setting the pixel format of the HDC to this:

```
  static PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR window_pixel_format_desc =
{
    sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
    1,
    PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,    //Flags
    PFD_TYPE_RGBA,            //The kind of framebuffer. RGBA or palette.
    8,                        //Colordepth of the framebuffer.
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    32,                        //Number of bits for the depthbuffer
    0,                        //Number of bits for the stencilbuffer
    0,                        //Number of Aux buffers in the framebuffer.
    PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
    0,
    0, 0, 0
};
```

Comment: What version of OpenGL is your context? Immediate mode rendering is deprecated in modern OpenGL, and non-existent in the core profile and OpenGL ES.

Comment: Also, the color depth of the HDC should be 24 for RGB (or 32 for RGBA), as [shown here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318284(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your comments. The version of OpenGL I am using is 4.5.0 and changing the color depth to 24 bits didn't fix my problem, although I can see how this is the correct value for this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.

First, you are never calling `glViewport`. You need to do that to set up the size of your render surface. The viewport should be set to use the whole window, so you'll need to use Win32 functions to query the client size of the window.

Second is this:

> ```
> glTranslatef(0, 0, -5);
> ```

Why is that there? This serves no purpose, and it causes the Z component of your triangles to become -5. Which is outside of the [-1, 1] Z range you get with OpenGL's default state.

Comment: Thanks Nicol, your answer got me closer to the solution but not quite there. So I added the glViewport with the size of the window and I got the window completely black, so then I tried using half the width and height and what I got was a black square one quarter of the window size black, while the rest of the area kept flipping colors (blue and red). Again nothing gets rendered to the screen.I suspect I am not selecting the correct buffer to draw and clear. Any ideas on how to fix that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I missed the fact that I was drawing a black square the size of the rendering area!

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost if your goal is to "get pixels from OpenGL into a DC" then doing it via a Window DC is very problematic. For one you're completely dependent on the window pixel management. Things like pixel ownership, window visibility, window clipping, etc. all can negatively impact your rendering outcome.

Another important thing to consider is, that you can set the pixelformat of a window only *once*! For offscreen rendering you have 2 options (or 3, depending on if the host system supports EGL and the EGL environment gives you offscreen rendering):

- create a hidden/invisible helper window to serve the DC for OpenGL and render into a *framebuffer object*. This is by far the preferrable solution at the current data (year 2016)
- create a PBuffer to serve the DC for OpenGL and render to that DC
- create an offscreen EGL context. Offscreen EGL can support direct offscreen surfaces, thus no framebuffer object is required. Or an offscreen context without a main surface thus a framebuffer objects is strictly required.

Out of the above options *only* the PBuffer method gives you a relaible way to *BitBlt* between DCs. However PBuffers are about as easy/difficult to create as an invisible window and framebuffer objects give you by far much more control. Also unlike PBuffers the contents of a framebuffer object destination (texture or renderbuffer) are forbidden to suddenly "vanish" (PBuffers may become invalid at any time).

The most reliable way to get images out of OpenGL into "something" that can be used with DC operations is to create a DIBSECTION (*[CreateDIBSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*) and read the image data into it with *glReadPixels*.

Comment: Hi datenwolf, I have already tried option number 2 and failed. Can you elaborate a bit on option 1? What do you mean by invisible window and how can it be attached to a DC? thanks

Comment: @vfiskewl: Essentially you follow through all the steps required to create  Window and configure it for OpenGL, but do not call `ShowWindow` on it and also do not use the `WS_SHOW` style. The important bit is using a framebuffer object as rendering target. There are plenty of framebuffer object tutorials out there.

Comment: @datenwolf: I think his problem is a little more basic than that. He's saying that rendering to a window isn't working. I highly doubt that switching to an FBO and blitting to the default framebuffer would suddenly cause it to work. Also, there's *nothing at all* wrong with rendering directly to a default framebuffer for a window.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I was under the impression that OP wants to fetch the framebuffer contents for use with GDI operations. If not that my whole answer it kind of moot, naturally.